# Scala .map(toString()) gives List of Char

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I tried to make my own map method in Scala and this is the result:

```
def map[A, B](f: A => B)(as: List[A]): List[B] =
    for (i <- as) yield f(i)
```

And if I try to convert a List[Int] to a List[String]:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)   //> list  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
map(toString()) (list)           //> res0: List[Char] = List(e, b, u, n, g)
```

I get the same result if I try:

```
list.map(toString())             //> res1: List[Char] = List(e, b, u, n, g)
```

My Question: Why gives toString() not a List("1","2"...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `toString()` on the current object (which apparently returns something like "?ebung...") and passing the resulting string as an argument to `map`.

So you might expect that to produce a type error because `map` expects a function, but you're passing a string. However strings count as functions too (because `RichString` implements the `Function1[Int, Char]` trait) that take an integer and return the character at that index. So that's why you get a list containing those characters.

To do what you meant to do (create a function that calls `toString` on its argument), you can either use `x => x.toString` or `_.toString` for short.